# Jface TableViewer set ContentProvider LabelProvider without update

Tags: java, jface, tableviewer

I am looking for a way to set the ContentProvider and LabelProvider of a `JFace` `TableViewer` without triggering a refresh.

The background of my Problem is:

- I am dynamically changing the Columns of the TableViewer
- I am locally defining new input data for the table.
- This leads to the problem that the old input data is used to display the new column arrangement -> index can get out of bounds

My (ugly) solution up to now is: before I change the columns, I add content/labelprovider to the viewer and set the input to null. If you know of anything cleaner, please let us know.

Comment: How dynamic are the columns? Could you have 2 or 3 tables with only one visible at a time?

Comment: @greg-449 There is a switch button to switch between two tables. But somehow I do not like the idea of having two tables. Once the switch is done between the tables, the old input objects shall be deleted.